# How to control overlapping text for long URLs

Tags: html, overlap

I have a comment section which is of a certain width. When I post a long URL, this text is overlapping as there is no spaces in between. How to fix this in HTML

Comment: If any of the answers below have helped you please consider marking one as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution in pure HTML. If you can use JavaScript or AJAX, you can convert the URL into a real link and replace the text part with only the first 20-30 characters of the URL: [http://some.com/a...](http://some.com/a-really-long-URL)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there's no HTML way to do this. Since it's display/design related you can use CSS:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

This might work too:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

[Overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_overflow.asp) & [Word-wrap](http://www.css3.com/css-word-wrap/) links.

Edit: `overflow: hidden` will hide the text that extends beyond the size of its container and `word-wrap: break-word` should force a break in the word.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options. You could amend your comment system server-side so that it automatically puts in a line break if a word is over a certain length.

Or, you could set the CSS style overflow to hidden, scroll, or something like that to prevent the containing DIV of the comment from being stretched - that could do the trick too.